# i have mvc5 site i want to add comments in storydetails view when i write comment , this comment appear in _index but in another page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have details page in home folder , and i want to add user comments in storydetails view , but when i write comment it will appear in _index but in another page , i want that comment appear in details view , i used partialView for _Create Comment View and _Index to View Comments how can i make that??

HomeController

```
 public ActionResult _Index()
    {

        return View(db.Comments.ToList());
    }



    public ActionResult _Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Comments/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult _Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Content,Date,")] Comments comment)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("_Index");
        }

        return View(comment);
    }
```

CommentsModel

```
public int Id { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public virtual Story story { get; set; }
```

Details View
here i write this in atop details view
@model Tawasol.Models.Story

```
@Html.Partial("_Create", new Tawasol.Models.Comments())


    @Html.Partial("_Index", new List<Tawasol.Models.Comments> { new Tawasol.Models.Comments() })
```